# Locating a broken submission

Tags: webforms

We've used Webform to create a form, which users are supposed to fill and submit.

A part of this form contains tables, with cells, that are supposed to be calculated to a total for each column in those tables. However, the one who created the form, used text-fields for the cells and "Computed Twig" for the "sum cell". This has created quite the headache.

If for some reason a user writes anything other than a number say 100k/100' instead of 100000, then presses the button to "save draft" - the form crashes, with the following:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in _*TwigTemplate*

drilling down, it references the following:

> Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->renderInline('{#
> inline_template_start #}{{ data.f1a + data.f1b + data.f1c + data.f1d
> }}', Array)

The PROBLEM though, is that this is now saved and if the user tries to open their form to continue their work, it crashes. If an administrator tries to view their form, it crashes.

So my question is simply if there is a way to find this form on the filesystem and fix it there?
I'm also baffled that there is no check in the function that tries to sum numbers, that catches this error ...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! When you export your site's config, you can indeed fix the form in a way to add some element validation that allows users to enter only numbers. I think this can be found under "pattern" where you can enter Regex and an error message you want to have displayed. But the form **submissions** exist only in the database; and to fix them you could use some batch process maybe from a `hook_update_N` implementation, that loads all submissions and then get the desired element value, check for letters, remove them, set the new value and resave the submission.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sure I can see how everyone creating a form could do that(and think of that), but wouldn't it be logical for a function that tries to do a mathematical operation to: a) wash the input, b) check if the input are infact numbers, c) warn the user that this is not a good idea, d) catch such errors and not store them in the database in the first place? I can't even seem to find a database file anywhere i the docker container, so I'm completely stumped on how to even begin to fix it.